# Find corresponding .INF file for device driver

Tags: windows, drivers, inf

I am trying to solve a problem with [devcon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/ff544780(v=vs.96)) for which I need to locate the INF file for a device driver.

I can find out which device driver a device is using via the device manager (driver details). It will point me to the driver, in my case, stored in C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\e1i63x64.sys.

Where can I find the corresponding INF file?

Comment: Look for the corresponding folder in `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository`

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: @n8te that's will do fine as answer by the way

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `.inf` file will be located in a corresponding folder (in your case, the folder name should start with e1i63x64) inside the following directory:

```
C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository
```

Answer (score 7):

May be very late to share but there is an easier way to do this!

1. Open Device Manager :
   Win + R > devmgmt.msc
2. Scroll and find the driver of interest
3. Right click and select "Properties" from pop-up menu.
4. In the next window, go to "Details" tab.
5. From the "Property" drop-down list, select `Inf Name`. Value pane should show the correct inf name for this driver now.

The value should show the inf name.
example, value may look something like > `oem100.inf`

Next open "cmd" as administrator and enter the following command > `dism /Online /get-drivers /format:table > C:\temp\drivers.txt`

Open this file in text editor and you should see a table like structure and search for the name of the INF file from Step-6 above.
Next, locate the filename printed next to it.

For example, if INF name is `oem100.inf` the value next (to the right) could look something like `e1d65x64.inf`

Next Step, take this name (for example, `e1d65x64`) and copy.

Next Step, go to `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository`, and paste the previously copied text into search bar.

Wait till search ends.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

dism /Online /get-drivers /format:table > C:\temp\drivers.txt
There seems to be an error in this code
The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).